# How do you erase ESP32 wifi Smartconfig credentials from flash?

Tags: esp32

I am using esp32 smartconfig to setup wifi credentials and it is working reliably.   I want to be able to erase the credentials which are stored somewhere in flash from my arduino esp32 sketch.

The only way I have been able to erase the credentials (I'm not sure where they are stored) is to erase the entire flash using esptool.py from my Windows PC:

```
esptool.py --chip esp32 --port com8 erase_flash
```

I would like to just be able to erase the credentials from my sketch so a user without a pc would have this capability.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided much details on your implementation, but if assuming the standard ESP-IDF implementation then the WiFi credentials are stored in Flash on the default NVS partition named "nvs" ([overview](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-jumpstart/en/latest/networkconfig.html#nvs-persistent-key-value-store)). You can easily perform an erase cycle on the entire partition which will erase everything stored in your device.

Alternatively you can hunt down the specific NVS keys used by the ESP WiFi component to store the credentials and erase only those. This is slightly risky as they haven't open-sourced the WiFi drivers and might change the implementation at any time. With that in mind, current ESP IDF 4.2 seems to store those keys in the default NVS partition under namespace "nvs.net80211". The relevant key names would appear to be "sta.authmode", "sta.ssid" and "sta.pswd".

Comment: Thanks.  That is exactly what I needed.   I am using the standard ESP-IDF implementation but in an Arduino environment.  I was able to print them out but not erase them:    esp_wifi_get_config(WIFI_IF_STA, &conf);  // load wifi settings to struct comf
  rssiSSID = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(conf.sta.ssid);
  password = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(conf.sta.password);

Comment: I adapted the code from here to be called as a subroutine and it is the only implementation I have found which allows the use of smartconfig reliably: https://gist.github.com/kakopappa/8e610c0b64361373994a21f9f3b62181

Answer (score 2):

Anyone else bumps into this, there is esp_wifi_restore() which will clear the wifi credentials without wiping out the NVS.

Source [https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/4108]

Answer (score 0):

You can erase it with the [ESP32 Networking API](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/network/esp_wifi.html). Here are two examples to reset and manage the credentials:

```
#include <esp_wifi.h>

void Network_reset()
{
   wifi_config_t current_conf;
   esp_wifi_get_config((wifi_interface_t)ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &current_conf);
   memset(current_conf.sta.ssid, 0, sizeof(current_conf.sta.ssid));
   memset(current_conf.sta.password, 0, sizeof(current_conf.sta.password));
   esp_wifi_set_config((wifi_interface_t)ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &current_conf);
}

void Set_wifi_credentials(String ssid, String pwd)
{
   wifi_config_t current_conf;
   esp_wifi_get_config((wifi_interface_t)ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &current_conf);
   memcpy(current_conf.sta.ssid, ssid.c_str(), sizeof(current_conf.sta.ssid));
   memcpy(current_conf.sta.password, pwd.c_str(), sizeof(current_conf.sta.password));
   esp_wifi_set_config((wifi_interface_t)ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &current_conf);
}
```

I have found the details after digging into the basic WiFi.begin() API.

Comment: Caution: Presently esp_wifi_set_config() only works if the WiFi interface (STA) is already enabled.

Comment: Cannot test, but I’m not so sure… I am setting the credentials in AP mode, then execute a restart. The device connects to the Wi-Fi.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using **PlatformIO** on **VSCode** you have the option "**Erase Flash**" in Platform IO left menu (when you click on ET head at the 'left' menu).

Be sure the ESP was reseted and in flash mode. (same to place a new code on it)

[Erasing flash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98gcP.png)

Comment: This wipes everything.

Comment: Thank you for checking my answer. Should I delete it to not confuse another person? Or should be here to people understand what can happen if they do that?